# iframe height set to 100% without any result - using Firefox v14

Tags: html, iframe, styles, height

I am working on a code currently where I have set the height of my iframe to 100% but it does not seem to work at all. I have tried to strip unnecessary code from it to demonstrate the issue, view the code here (mind the inline css): http://jsfiddle.net/VfKqR/

And here it is:

```
<!-- Start full page container -->
<div style="min-width: 830px; width: 100%; height: 100%; float: left;">

<!-- Start scoop menu -->
<div style="width: 188px; float: left;">

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>

<a href="http://rambler.ru" target="scoop" style="font-size:13px; letter-spacing: 0.7px; font-weight: bold;">Link tester</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<!-- End scoop menu -->
</div>

<!-- spacer between divs -->
<div style="width: 20px; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- Start iframe -->
<div style="min-width: 622px; width:74%; height: 100%; float: left;">

<iframe id="scoop" name="scoop" src="http://www.yahoo.com" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiframe" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" width="100%" height="100%">

<!-- End iframe -->
</div>

<!-- End full page container -->
</div>
```

Nothing that I can do seem to fix the height to 100%. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I just tested this in Safari and it worked fine, however in the latest version of Firefox (v14.0.1), it does not work.

Comment: What browser are you testing it in? Chrome seems to work.

Comment: I am trying to make to go 100% of the users screen. Same way that width works when set to 100%. I am using FireFox v14.

Comment: If you add `html,body{height:100%}` it'll go all the way in FF too, but your window will be limited to the viewport size.

Comment: Turns out that in FF, you have to make sure all surrounding elements of the iframe have to have height:100% too (including the parent html element)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this small jquery script I've just wrote to achieve it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){var height = $(window).height();
            $('iframe').css('height', height)
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VurLy/

Comment: This is a very interesting approach that solved my question. However, it does not seem to understand the height of my current window, only my resolution. Is there any way to adjust it so that it follows my screen size?

Comment: Or to have it on 90% rather than 100%?

Comment: It is following the browser window size, well, at least here. However, if you would like the height to match the parent element you would rather use something like this:

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){var height = innerHeight(#perentelementid);
            $('iframe').css('height', height)
        });`


But then the parent element/wrapper must have stated the height value.

Comment: I mean the parent element/wrapper must have stated explicit value (no percentage).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED FOR JAVASCRIPT
javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = "html, body{height: 100%;}";
document.head.appendChild(sheet);
</script>
```

html:

```
<div style="min-width: 622px; width:74%; height: 100%; float: left;">​......
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the **html, body{height: 100%;}** inline in the body? I am developing this for a CMS that does not allow me to edit the header or to use a stylesheet (which is why I am using inline CSS).

Comment: Can't you use the style tag inside your document? `<style type="text/css">html, body{height:100%;}</style>`

Comment: No, I can only edit past the body tag unfortunately. What solution do I have left?

Comment: changed my answer, should work aslong as this CMS lets you execute javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my solution [Setting iframe to take remaining space in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414427/setting-iframe-to-take-remaining-space-in-page/13484164#comment18457957_13484164) without any JS.

You will need to clear some `float`'s most likely (as those are the reason the iFrame will not scale) and most likely you will need to refactor your code a bit.

Hope that helps.