# Setting iframe to take remaining space in page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, height

There are quite a lot of questions regarding iframe and it's height. Some are similar but not giving me the right answer. So let me explain my case:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AmVhK/3/show/
Editor: http://jsfiddle.net/AmVhK/3/

There is a table with 2 rows. First one contains a div #toolbar with **fixed** height. Second row contains a div which holds an iframe. I need the iframe to take the available space below the toolbar div.

Problem I am facing is in **IE standards mode** (supporting IE8+). *Let's say*, the height of the window is 1000px and height of toolbar is 200px, then the height of the iframe is also 1000px and so has scrollbars. I need the iframe to have height of (page height-toolbar height).

It would be good if there is a CSS solution. Using JavaScript to get the height available and setting it to the iframe or it's containing div is the last resort solution for me :)

Setting the toolbar or iframe to absolute position also won't work for my use case. **Markup change is ok if necessary** (if you want to remove tables)

I have already set the following CSS:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
```

Any good solution to implement it.

Comment: I think u want to this http://jsfiddle.net/AmVhK/6/

Comment: @RohitAzad, iframe is still taking more space than the available.

Comment: Are you set in stone about using tables?

Comment: hmmmm, go oldschool and use a frameset ? ( like http://www.meingutscheincode.de/gutschein-anzeigen/50a266b10ae86b2818000001 for example )

Comment: Oh no, frameset, one of my client still have one in 2012 !

Comment: well it may not be state of the art but it will definitively do what is required here

Comment: Have you come with a final answer here?

Comment: This is nothing else than the standard issue of CSS2 not offering enough tools to force an element to the remaining height of it's parent. In case you are not satisfied with the answers posted, I can provide a strong CSS solution. If you want the short story, it's about `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: @mystrdat, can you provide the solution?

Answer (score 4):

OK here's my attempt at this, there's an issue with the iframe wanting to have a horizontal scroll in IE7 but the layout is good, I had to give up because fighting with IE7 makes me want to chew out my own eyes, hopefully someone could expand from here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>iframelayout</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }

            div, iframe {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
            }

            .container {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: #222;
            }

            .toolbar {
                height: 200px;
                background: #aaa;
            }

            .iframe-container {
                position: absolute;
                top: 200px;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                background: #555;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }

            .iframe-container iframe {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="toolbar">

            </div>
            <div class="iframe-container">
                <iframe src="https://c9.io/" frameborder="0">Your browser is kaput!</iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. 
is it possible to implement this without using absolute position. The height of the toolbar will change with animation on user interaction and it varies. The iframe should move along with it so I guess it is better to leave this to the browser.

Comment: would it be possible to also animate the `.iframe-container` top property along with the toolbar?

Comment: for example you could supply a callback to the toolbar animation that sets the .iframe-container { top: 200px; } to be the calculated height of the toolbar

Comment: The height of the toolbar would be vary with different buttons in it pressed coz different set of functionalities require different markups and heights to show.

Comment: With jquery callback, the iframe will only animate after the toolbar has finished it's animation which is not desired.

Comment: @sv_in the toolbar requiring flexible height makes the whole issue dramatically harder, you should mention that in the OP. With set height, it's rather simple without tables and very clean code. When I wrote the OP comment, I wasn't aware you want the toolbar flexible, that's a gamechanger, will have to rewrite the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution tested in IE8 and FF17

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            *
            {
                border: 0;
                line-height: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            html,
            body
            {
                height: 100%;
            }

            #layout
            {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                            overflow-y: hidden;

                background-color: green;
            }

            #toolbar
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 200px;

                background-color: blue;
            }

            #content-wrapper
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 200px;
                bottom: 0px;

                width: 100%;

                background-color: red;
            }

            #content
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layout">
            <div id="toolbar">

            </div>
            <div id="content-wrapper">
                <iframe id="content" name="content" src="https://c9.io/" border="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Our answers are very similar but I threw in a overflow-y: hidden; to eliminate that issue :)

Comment: EDIT : border: 0; line-height: 0; fixed 100% in FF, width is perfect in IE8 (don't have IE9 and 7), line-height could be reset in toolbar of course.

Comment: Really strange in FireBug to see the height where perfect and line-height: 0; fixed into Firefox.. IE need overflow-y: hidden; Cross-Browsing is an art!

Comment: is it possible to implement this without using absolute position. The height of the toolbar will change with animation on user interaction and it varies. The iframe should move along with it so I guess it is better to leave this to the browser.

Comment: You can do dynamic part with JavaScript to update toolbar height and content-wrapper top, but not found solution without absolute positionning!

Answer (score 3):

This is as clean as it can get minding your original question mentions the toolbar has a **fixed** height. Minimal code, no wrapper elements and no tables necessary, IE8+/Chrome/Fox compatible.

However, in the comments of Dale's solution, you mention the toolbar height being flexible instead and a requirement for the iframe to adjust - that is a major gamechanger and I would suggest you strip that of your requirements as it's practically impossible to achieve in CSS2 without extra JS and/or horrendous CSS hacks. If you didn't want IE<=9 compatibility, this would be very possible using CSS3 flexbox.

Since the reason for the toolbar flexible height would be animation for different states as you mentioned, I would suggest you use the code below and animate the toolbar **height** and iframe **padding-top** at the same time to achieve the desired flexibility instead of just the toolbar height. It does not require any extra JavaScript outside of the animation itself, so the only "disadvantage" is to animate 2 properties instead of 1. The rest of the layout will finely adjust.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; /* animate this */
}
#cblt_content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 200px; /* and this */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="toolbar">Toolbar</div>
<iframe id="cblt_content" src="https://c9.io/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Getting rid of the vertical scroll

Using this code should leave with only the inner (`iframe`) scrolls:

```
html, body
{
    height:    100%;
    width:     100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. The `width` is needed (like with `absolute`).
2. You are right about `absolute` not helping you.
3. This actually makes sense for what you are trying to achieve (if I got it right).

**Browser Support:**

Might be a little buggy, but should be supported as of IE7 ([quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t28)).

---

*Hope I got the question right.*

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title> - Webduos Demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            *{ border: 0;  line-height: 0;  margin: 0; padding: 0; }

            html, body {  height: 100%;  }

            #layout { position: relative; width: 100%; min-height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden; background-color: green; }

            #toolbar {  width: 100%;  height: 160px;  background-color: blue;  }

            #content-wrapper {  position:absolute;  top:180px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; background-color: #0000dd;  }

            #content {width: 100%; height: 100%;  }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layout">
            <div id="toolbar">

            </div>
            <div id="content-wrapper">
                <iframe id="content" name="content" src="https://google.com/" border="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply hide the parent scroll bar and get what you want. Like by simply adding overflow-y hidden:

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it! Here's the quick preview link: http://jsfiddle.net/AmVhK/15/show/

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    #contentiframewrapper, #cblt_content {
    /* max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 99.9%;*/
    height: 99.9%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    }
    #toolbar {
        height: 100px !important;
        background-color: #CCC;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
<table width="100%" height="99.6%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" id="toolbar">Toolbar
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" height="80.5%">
                <div align="center" id="contentiframewrapper">
                     <iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" name="cblt_content" id="cblt_content" src="https://c9.io/" border="0"></iframe>
                </div>
           </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

I've tested it in both Chrome and IE8 and it works on my side. It might bug in JSFiddle in IE8 but it shouldn't if you view it as a separate page (in normal conditions that is).

**Edit:** 
Made some slight changes to the original code. However, you will have to change the `<td>` that holds the iFrame height value to the new height if you change the height of the toolbar. With IE there is no magic % value (unless you use JS, which you don't want of course) for it, it's just trial and error.

Comment: A height in %'s wont take bigger screens into consideration. So though it might fit nicely on your screen.. if i have double your resolution(or half), things might -and probably will- be messed up.

Comment: Tried messing up with the browser size, the scroll bar will show up if you go under 1/3 of the screen (at least this is what i'm experiencing), the iFrame will scale to bigger browser sizes without any issues, btw i'm working on a 15" laptop it might pose issues with netbooks, but without JS, i think this is close to the best solution out there (not referring to my solution, to using % values for the height).

Comment: I think I have to agree. I've fixed this problem before, but allways with a few javascript tricks.

Comment: I downvoted because it's not a good solution. Using tables for this is unnecessary and semantics-wise wrong and the height percentage playground you're trying to suggest is creating more issues than it tries to solve.

Comment: Well the owner said that markup change is ok "if necessary", from that i personally understand that you can change the markup but it isn't really preferable. I just provided a solution for what existed but do tell me what do you use "with tables" and without JS to fix the problem? I see you are very knowledgeable in this direction so i may have things to learn from you.

Comment: I'm aware of what the owner said, yet we're here to provide the best possible answer - in many cases this means turning the solution upside down. I've left my answer to the question above.