# How to set an iframe to automatically fill empty body space in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Okay, so I need to be able to have a page which fills 100% of the screen with no overflow at all. I have an iframe at the top of the page and an img at the bottom.

I need to be able to have the iframe automaticaly set its height to fill all of the remaining space in the document.

heres some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    img             {
                border:0px;
                padding:0px;
                float:left;
                width:33.3333%;
            }
    body            {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                margin:0px;
            }
    iframe          {
                overflow-y: scroll;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                border:0px;
                padding:0px;
                width:100%;
                height:auto;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- INNER CONTENT -->
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="..." ></iframe>
<!-- BOTTOM BUTTONS -->
<center>
    <div>
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img3.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="page2.html">
        <img src="img1.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="page3.html">
        <img src="img2.png" />
    </a>
    </div>
</center>
</body>
```

I need some sort of calculation that I can set for the iframe tag. something like

```
<iframe height="'bodyheight-imgheight'"></iframe>
```

any sort of answer is good wether it be CSS, HTML, Js, jQ..

[EDIT]
I know I could simply set the height of the images and do a manual setting for the height of the iframe but I want the images height to change with their width

Thanks for all the replies, I used this answer to solve my question:
http://jsfiddle.net/AmVhK/6/

which was posted in:
[Setting iframe to take remaining space in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414427/setting-iframe-to-take-remaining-space-in-page)

Comment: will help a lot if image dimensions are known otherwise can't set heights until they are all loaded. Height of a container full of unloaded image tags will be 0

Answer (score 0):

With javascript its not so bad, you can just calculate the height off all the contents in the parent and then subtract that from the parents height. So if the iframe, `$frame` is the element in question you can do:

```
height = $frame.parent().height();//height of parent
$frame.siblings.each(function() {
   height -= $(this).height();
});
$frame.height(height); //set frame height to remaining height of parent
```

So if $frames parent is the body or has 100% height it should take up the remaining space on the page.

Note: you will have to recalculate the heights if the user resizes the page

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you don't have **an** image, but three images (and the center tag shouldn't be used anymore).

You'll have to wait until the images are loaded, which they will be on window.onload, and then get the total height of the images, but as they are floated, that won't be accurate either, so what you really need to do is get the CSS right.

It's not the images that should be floated, as they aren't really siblings, but the anchors, and it seems all the anchors are within a DIV, so targeting that DIV seems like the right move.

The tricky part is getting that DIV to be the same size as any and all images it may contain, and a common trick is to float it as well, as that will make it autoadjust properly, but if you have other content (which you don't) you'll need to clear the float.

Knowing all this, we can add an ID to the DIV so it's easier to target :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
<div id="container"> 
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CC-image.jpeg" />
    </a>
    <a href="page2.html">
        <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSDIjq8HKf234I87kaL1SPTOyop7_GGSzAEG5GR5-Atuo1T7nIQ" />
    </a>
    <a href="page3.html">
        <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhpRmIys5SOHo3jSoyibVFBgZtcXVRmQHwv3Uc-uC7-nUKLYGc" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And change the CSS accordingly

```
#container {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
a {
    position: relative;
    width:33.3333%;
    float:left;
    height: auto;
}
img {
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
iframe {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

and then all we have to do is get the height of the window and subtract the height of the DIV, but as noted, we have to wait until all the images are loaded.
To make it work everytime the window size is changed, we can attach it to the `resize` event, and then also trigger that event on page load :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(this).on('resize', function () {
        var imageHeight = $('#container')[0].clientHeight,
            windowHeight = $(this).height();

        $('iframe').height(windowHeight - imageHeight);
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cSLP2/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the actual dimensions of images and assuming they are each the same can set a variable for aspect ratio of images. Based on window width this allows calculating the image display height before they are even loaded

```
var imageW= 400,/* adjust accordingly*/
    imageH=300
var ratio= imageW/imageH;
```

Using jQuery on page load (occurs before images loaded):

```
$(function(){
  var footerH= ratio * $(window).width() /3 ;
  $('iframe').height( $(window).height() - footerH);

})
```